# Procedural brush stroke texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I want to make some procedural textures that look like a bunch of brush strokes, pencil scribbles, or the like. The core component being that they are a collection of strokes that go mostly in the same direction and overlay each other, but each contains some smaller bristle marks, scratches, grain, etc. Any ideas on the best way to do these things?

Here are a few examples of what I want to make off google (which I assume were done by hand)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where you want to create it? In Blender?

Comment: Yes, with Cycles material Nodes. I could make them by hand in photoshop, but I'm trying to avoid image textures any more than possible due to VRAM.

Comment: oh, sorry, I've read it too fast. I've tought that you want to make brush for grease pencil or texture paint :)

Comment: Have you considered using a procedurally mapped image texture? (box mapping?)

Comment: @gandalf3 I've thought of using image textures with various mapping or random coords, or several image textures that are then mixed together in different random combinations and with procedurals. But I figured I'd ask if anyone had come up with a good method that was purely procedural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here I got it. I think that matches it pretty well.

[image: Disortion]

[image: Texture]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the first image, I think a combination of wave and noise textures, with colorramp control and some offset-repeats might work. I will experiment and get back with results.