# Procedural brush stroke texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, procedural

How do I create a procedural brush stroke texture in cycles such that:

(A) There is a distinct and noticeable shift in the saturation and value of the color(s) as shown in :
[image]

(B) Each "stroke" simulates pen pressure in the size on the leading and trailing end of the "stroke" :
[image]

(C) The strokes should have randomized noise variance in the stroke and around its fringes :
[image]

(D) There should be no blank spaces between the strokes to expose the mesh underneath :
[image]

I have attempted to do this in cycles using the following nodes :
[image]

1 - controls intensity

2 - controls rotation and scale

3 - creates the stroke effect

4 - adds noise

5 - controls sharpness of the color

Now, the problem is, I'm not getting the desired effect as stated above and instead the nodes outputs as follows :

[image]

What am I missing here?

PS: I'm aware of this : [Procedural brush stroke texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69201/procedural-brush-stroke-texture) and part of my setup is based on it, but the results aren't satisfactory.

Hope you can figure it out. Thanks in advance.

PPS : closest thing to my desired output would be :
[image]

Comment: You can paint with a frame sequence ;-)

Comment: @3pointedit le what?

Comment: You can make an animation of paint tip over time, then use that for your brush texture. The animation becomes the bristles and paint bleed during the stroke. Also there's this other solution to varying the stroke and application https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124080/animating-dynamic-paint-with-noise-texture

Comment: @3pointedit at first glance, for something as simple as a plane, that would be easy to do, but how about something as complex as tree?